# Django Conditional update based on Foreign key values / joined fields

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to do a conditional update based on the value of a field on a foreign key. Example:

```
Model Kid: id, parent (a foreign key to Parent), has_rich_parent
Model Parent: id, income
```

So say I have a query set of A. I wanna update each item's `has_guardian` in A based on the value of `age` on the Kid's parent in one `update`. What I was trying to do is

```
queryset_of_kids.update(
    has_rich_parent=Case(
       When(parent__income__gte=10, then=True)
       default=False
    )
)
```

But this is giving me an error `Joined field references are not permitted in this query`. Which I am understanding it as joined fields / pursuing the foreignkey relationships aren't allowed in `update`s.

I'm wondering if there's any other way to accomplish the same thing, as in updating this queryset within one update call? My situation has a couple more fields that I'd like to verify instead of just `income` here so if I try to do filter then update, the number of calls will be linear to the number of arguments I'd like to filter/update.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update question with `queryset_of_kids`

Comment: Try `When(Greatest(F('parent__income'), 9), then=True)
       default=False` don't forget to add `from django.db.models import F` and `from django.db.models.functions import Greatest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the models that I assume you're using:

```py
from django.db import models

class Kid(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    has_rich_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Parent(models.Model):
    income = models.IntegerField()
```

You can use a `Subquery` to update the `has_rich_parent` field.

- The subquery filters on the primary key `pk` of the surrounding query using `.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk'))`.
- It uses a `Q` query object to obtain whether the parent income is >= 10.

```py
from .models import Kid, Parent
from django.db.models import Q, Subquery, OuterRef

Kid.objects.update(has_rich_parent=Subquery(
    Kid.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk'))
               .values_list(Q(parent__income__gte=10))))
```

That command produces the following SQL query:

```sql
UPDATE "more_kids_kid"
SET "has_rich_parent" = (
  SELECT (U1."income" >= 10) AS "q1"
  FROM "more_kids_kid" U0
  INNER JOIN "more_kids_parent" U1 ON (U0."parent_id" = U1."id")
  WHERE U0."id" = ("more_kids_kid"."id")
)
```

This query isn't as efficient as a `SELECT`-then-`UPDATE` query. However, your database may be able to optimize it.