# Conditionally bulk_create or bulk_update model instance fields based on the conditional equality of two foreign key related fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm trying to `bulk_create` or `bulk_update` instances of a model `Matchup`, where two of its fields are dependent on the equality or lack thereof of two of its related fields' reverse relationships.

The `Matchup` has both a `home_team` and `away_team`, both of which are `ForeignKey` fields. There's are also `is_divisional` and `is_conference` fields to denote whether the matchup is between teams in the same division or conference.

```
class Matchup(models.Model):
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(
        "teams.Team",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="home_matchups",
    )
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(
        "teams.Team",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="away_matchups",
    )
    is_divisional = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_conference = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The `Team` model also has two `ForeignKey` fields, `conference` and `division`.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    conference = models.ForeignKey(
        "leagues.Conference",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="teams",
    )
    division = models.ForeignKey(
        "leagues.Division",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="teams",
    )
```

So the goal here is to check whether the `Matchup.home_team` and `Matchup.away_team` belong to the same conference or division. If so, `is_conference`/`is_divisional` respectively should be `True`.

Here's what I initially had. It works, but leads to hundreds of duplicate queries. I perform this `bulk_update` after all the objects are created in bulk.

```
for matchup in matchup_objs:
    if matchup.home_team.division == matchup.away_team.division:
        matchup.is_divisional = True
    if matchup.home_team.conference == matchup.away_team.conference:
        matchup.is_conference = True
Matchup.objects.bulk_update(matchup_objs, ["is_divisional", "is_conference"])
```

In an attempt to reduce the duplicate queries, I tried using a `Case()` expression during the `bulk_create` of the objects like so.

```
matchup_objs = Matchup.objects.bulk_create(
    [
        Matchup(
            home_team=home_team,
            away_team=away_team,
            is_conference=Case(
                When(home_team__conference=F('away_team__conference'), then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False)
            ),
            is_divisional=Case(
                When(home_team__division=F('away_team__conference'), then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False)
            ),
        )
        for matchup in matchups
    ]
)
```

But I'm getting a `FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query`. I believe this is because joins aren't allowed for a `bulk_create` operation.

I thought about using a `SubQuery()` here based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806414/django-conditional-update-based-on-foreign-key-values-joined-fields/70807588#70807588) answer but I'm not sure how to accomplish that as the `When()` statement expects a parameter name and the `home_team__conference` lookup is what's throwing the FieldError.

Is there a way to accomplish this or do I need to resort to raw SQL here?

Comment: "Here's what I initially had. It works, but leads to hundreds of duplicate queries." - Are they a result of matchup.home_team.division == matchup.away_team.division or bulk_update? maybe you just lack the select_related

Comment: @DavidWenzel The extra queries are a result of the attribute access, correct. Bulk update produces a single query. I will try using select_related (first time needing it). It would just be something like this right? Matchup.objects.filter(foo=foo).select_related('home_team__division', 'home_team__conference', 'away_team__division', 'away_team__conference') .Then iterate through that and any subsequent access shouldn't produce duplicate lookups.

Comment: yup that should do the trick and cache the data

Comment: That helped eliminate 100's of duplicate queries. Thank you! I also had to append each matchup to a new list and pass that list to bulk_update. Feel free to post the solution as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. @DavidWenzel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the related attributes are not cached django will hit the database again and again for every attribute you access in the loop

```
for matchup in matchup_objs:
if matchup.home_team.division == matchup.away_team.division:
    matchup.is_divisional = True
if matchup.home_team.conference == matchup.away_team.conference:
    matchup.is_conference = True
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related

```
Matchup.objects.filter(foo=foo).select_related('home_team__division', 'home_team__conference', 'away_team__division', 'away_team__conference'
```